# How to add a DEFAULT VALUE stored to one Column

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I created my Table like this:

```
create table persona(
  id bigint (10) NOT NULL auto_increment, Nombre varchar(32) not null,
  appPaterno varchar (32) not null,
  appMaterno varchar (32),
  mail varchar (32) default '@hotmail.com', PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

My question is: how from Java send data and add that default into the same  column where the data will be stored?

Can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean by `default value` and *send that data add that default into...*?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a trigger that do that and 
make your insert code just as usual :D else you can try this ^^

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Connexion {

public static Connection connect()
{
    Connection c = null;
    try {

          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","onp","onp");

        } catch (Exception ex) 
        {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    return c;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    connect();
}
}




public class Persona 
{

    String Nombre;
    String PaterNo;
    String MaterNo;
    String Mail;

    public void insertPersonne()
    {
      try {
        Connection conn=Connexion.connect();
        String query="insert into persona(Nombre ,appPaterno ,appMaterno ,mail) values('"+Nombre+"','"+PaterNo+"','"+MaterNo+"','"+Mail+"@hotmail.com')";
        PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.executeQuery();
        conn.close();
      } catch (Exception ex) 
        {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... Works like a charm... Good idea.. Later i will use  triggers